# VBA to Call Python Script

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have a workbook that calls a python script in the same folder where it should then execute and create a new CSV file within that folder. However, I am having trouble getting the python script to execute from the VBA Call.

The python script runs fine when executed from within the IDE, but not when called from VBA. The Python CMD will open for a moment and then close but no CSV is produced

(For context the python script uses PDFPlumber to get data from whatever PDF is in the same file folder.

```
Sub Call_PDF_Reader()

Dim Summary_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PythonEXEPath, ScriptPath As String
Dim objShell As Object

Set Summary_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

PythonEXEPath = """C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe"""
'"C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe"

ScriptPath = """C:\Users\Name\OneDrive - Company\LR_Deal_Approval\Read_PDF.py"""

'RetVal = Shell(PythonEXEPath & " " & ScriptPath)

'MsgBox PythonEXEPath & " " & ScriptPath
objShell.Run PythonEXEPath & " " & ScriptPath


End Sub
```

Below here is the Python without all the functions inbetween:

```
"""Declare Variables"""

FILE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
dir_list = os.listdir(FILE_PATH)
pdf_file = ''
excel_file = ''

'Find the PDF in the folder'
for file in dir_list:
    file_type = file[file.find('.'):len(file)]
    if file_type == '.pdf':
        pdf_file = pdf_file = os.path.join(FILE_PATH, file)
        with pdfplumber.open(pdf_file) as pdf:
            page = pdf.pages[0]
            text = page.extract_text()
        continue

...
"""Output"""

dict = {'vars': Output_Data, 'invoice_amounts': Invoice_Amount, 'invoice_dates': Invoice_Date}
df_vars = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict,orient='index')
df_vars = df_vars.transpose()
df_vars.to_csv(os.path.join(FILE_PATH, 'PDF_OUTPUT.csv'))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA Calling Python Script Not Running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70966608/vba-calling-python-script-not-running)

Comment: No that was actually my post and It was suggested to me that I restate the question more clearly, I have closed the other one. Thanks though.

Comment: With exec you can capture the output `MsgBox objShell.exec(PythonEXEPath & " " & ScriptPath).StdOut.ReadAll`

Comment: This is the ouput: "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\Name\OneDrive - company\LR_Deal_Approval\Read_PDF.py"

Comment: What do you get with `MsgBox objShell.exec(PythonEXEPath & " --version ").StdOut.ReadAll`

Comment: Returns: Python 3.9.7

Comment: So the python exe is working, must be problem with script.This line looks odd `pdf_file = pdf_file = os.path.join(FILE_PATH, file)` but isn't the problem Add a `print(pdf_file)` statement after that line.

Comment: The result is: C:\Users\Name\OneDrive - Company\LR_Deal_Approval\04814 - Sureity - OF - 1_31_2022.pdf